# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Migration Issue after importing a project

Tags: migration, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Update to Worklight version 6.0. Even load sample apps from new version 6.0 web site and get this exception like this:

> An internal error occurred during: "Upgrade Worklight Projects".
>   loader constraint violation: when resolving method
>   "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Iterator;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the
>   current class, com/worklight/builder/skins/impl/SkinBuilderImpl, and
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved
>   class, org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils, have different Class objects
>   for the type org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter used in the
>   signature

None of the apps could be built and deployed in new 6.0 (Tried With JDK 1.6/1.7, Eclipse 4.2.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to find if you have apache commons IO installed in your Eclipse plugin directory.
That's the source of the conflict.
If you can, please try to:
1. stop the Eclipse
2. move the apache commons IO out of the plugin dir
3. start Eclipse, then close it.
4. move the commons IO back into the plugin dir.
5. Start Eclipse.

Does the problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

Have to use Eclipse is 4.2.2 Java Platform Enterprise Edition version but not Classic

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer above - only Eclipse Jave EE 4.2.2 for developers.