# IBM Worklight application builder error

Tags: ios, eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using **eclipse juno 4.2.1** and **IBM worklight 6.0** on my mac mini. since yesterday I am trying to build and deploy my application but its giving me "Worklight application builder" error.

here is the log:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Worklight application builder".
loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Iterator;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, com/worklight/builder/skins/impl/SkinBuilderImpl, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils, have different Class objects for the type o/filefilter/IOFileFilter;Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter;)Ljava/util/Iterator; used in the signature


and console shows this message :

[2013-09-25 15:18:46]             Starting build process: application 'TestApp', all environments
[2013-09-25 15:18:46]             com.worklight.shared.common.messages:tgn309.trigyn.com: tgn309.trigyn.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
                                  java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1466)
                                  com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.scanIPAddresses(GeneralUtil.java:581)
                                  com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.scanIPAddresses(GeneralUtil.java:549)
                                  com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil.getIPscanResults(GeneralUtil.java:642)
                                  com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.WSTServers.getServerHost(WSTServers.java:174)
                                  com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.WSTServers.getServerURL(WSTServers.java:661)
                                  com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.buildApplication(WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.java:325)
                                  com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.runInWorkspace(WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.java:158)
                                  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
                                  org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
[2013-09-25 15:18:46] FWLPL0010W: "localhost" was detected from the target server configuration. Using the primary IP address of the host machine, 10.30.1.102, to build the Worklight application(s). Consider using a fully qualified hostname (avoid using "localhost") or a valid IP address instead. The value can be modified by opening the configuration editor of Worklight Development Server from the "Servers" view.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Worklight does not support Eclipsr 4.2.1, please first upgrade to Eclipse 4.2.2 and try again in a New workspace.

Comment: I just rechecked my Eclipse version and its 4.2.2 but still I am getting above posted error.

Comment: Ensure you're using Eclipse Juno 4.2.2, either "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" or "Eclipse Classic" edition. Also, what edition of Worklight 6.0? Developer Edition (server running in eclipse) or Consumer/Enterprise edition (server running in eclipse, or standalone server - if the latter, what server?).

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno 4.2.2, Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers and Worklight 6.0 Developer Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the suggestion given in the following answer, as it seems somewhat related based on the error in your question: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Migration Issue after importing a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279461/ibm-worklight-6-0-migration-issue-after-importing-a-project)

Copy/paste:

> Please try to find if you have apache commons IO installed in your
>   Eclipse plugin directory. That's the source of the conflict.
>
> If you can, please try to:
>
> 1. stop the Eclipse
> 2. move the apache commons IO out of the plugin dir
> 3. start Eclipse, then close it
> 4. move the commons IO back into the plugin dir
> 5. Start Eclipse